# Is there any difference between bpy.path.basename and os.path.basename?

Tags: python, scripting, path

According to the [docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.path.html#bpy.path.basename) for `bpy.path.basename`:

> Equivalent to os.path.basename, but skips a “//” prefix.
>
> Use for Windows compatibility.

But on Windows, I don't see any difference between it and `os.path.basename`.

Are there any cases where the two functions will give different output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.path.basename` doesn't understand Blender's `//` prefix (denoting a path relative to the current blend file). `bpy.path.basename` does understand this. If your path is (or could be) a blend-file-relative path, use the `bpy.path.*` functions.

On Linux I don't see any difference either, don't have Windows handy at the moment to check there.

Comment: So the only edge case I was able to find was `os.path.basename('//dir/file.txt')` gives `''` instead of `'file.txt'`. `os.path.basename('//dir/dir2/file.txt')` and `os.path.basename('//file.txt')` both work correctly.